# C# Finding flexible datastructure for json data

Tags: c#, json, data-structures, nested

I am looking for a good datastructure for a table that will look like this:

```
Name   | ID | Time  | A3 | A2 | D6 | L4 | H1 | ...
Peter    01   11:01   1    4    8         1    ...
James    02   11:37   7         5    2    2    ...
....
```

The values of Name, ID and Time are given "manually" by my tool, all the columns after that ("A3", "A2",...) are coming from a json string like

```
{"A3":"7","D6":"5",...}
```

My problem ist, that these json values can have any name, and that I do not know which person will generate which values (in the sample, James does not have a value for A2).

**What kind of class/structure would be best to store this mix of variables?**

Of course it should be "easy" to add new lines if new values "arrive". And I also want to write this structure into a csv later, but that's not the problem here.

I tried a lot with List<> and Directory<> but did not manage to create anything that is easy to handle.

Thanks in advance!

**edit:** I finally used a combination of both answers:

```
public class ResultData
{
    public string currentName { get; set; }
    public string currentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime currentTimestamp { get; set; }
    public DataTable results { get; set; }

    public ResultData()
    {
        results = new DataTable();

        // must have columns
        results.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        results.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
        results.Columns.Add("Timestamp", typeof(DateTime));
    }


    public void AddResult(Dictionary<string, string> resultVars)
    {
        // TODO: check if person is already in list

        DataRow dr = results.NewRow();

        // add basics
        dr["Name"] = currentName;
        dr["ID"] = currentID;
        dr["Timestamp"] = currentTimestamp;

        // check columns
        foreach (var varName in resultVars)
        {
            // add column if needed
            if (!results.Columns.Contains(varName.Key))
            {
                results.Columns.Add(varName.Key);
            }

            // add values
            dr[varName.Key] = varName.Value;
        }

        //finally add row
        results.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

Working fine for me! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution which you find in C#,

The DataTable class stores rows and columns of data. It is part of the System.Data namespace. We add, select and iterate over stored data.

C# program that uses DataTable

```
 using System;
    using System.Data;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
        // Get the DataTable.
        DataTable table = GetTable();
        // ... Use the DataTable here with SQL.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This example method generates a DataTable.
        /// </summary>
        static DataTable GetTable()
        {

        // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
        return table;
        }
    }
```

One more Good thing is  Visual studio help you visual the data,

Try this it has many possibility with DataRow Class also, its fast and simple one to hold Table data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a class containing a Dictionary property?

```
public class MyClass{
  public int id {get; set;}
  public string name {get; set;}
  public Datetime time {get; set;}
  public Dictionary<string, string> {get;}
}
```